# My Google social login app is published but Still it show temporarily disabled this app

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google social login oauth api is verified and its status is published but when I try to login with new user it gives the temporarily disabled this app error.
Screenshot of oauth consent screen
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused because your application hasn't been approved for any [sensitive or restricted scopes](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#verification-types)

I would suggest you make sure that your application is verified for all the scopes and if not, submit your application for verification with all the scopes listed.

If non of the above works for you, you may contact [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/)